# Spring-Kafka : Issue while deserialising kafka message - class not in a "trusted package"?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I get the below exception because I produce from one project and the consumer consumes from another project. How can I fix this. Obviously the packages are not the same. So how can I ensure that there is proper json serialization.

```
The class 'com.lte.assessment.assessments.AssessmentAttemptRequest' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.lte.assessmentanalytics.model
```

Consumer Config

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfig {
    static Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap();

    static {
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    }


      @Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, AssessmentAttemptRequest> assessmentAttemptDetailsEntityConsumerFactory() {
    JsonDeserializer<AssessmentAttemptRequest> deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
    deserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.lte.assessment.assessments");
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(config, new StringDeserializer(), deserializer);
}

}
```

Producer Config

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ProducerFactory producerConfig() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap();

        config.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
        config.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class);
        config.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonSerializer.class);

        return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory(config);
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaTemplate kafkaTemplate() {
        return new KafkaTemplate(producerConfig());
    }

 @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory aaKafkaListenerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, AssessmentAttemptDetailsEntity> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(assessmentAttemptDetailsEntityConsumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can whitelist your package by changing `assessmentAttemptDetailsEntityConsumerFactory()` like this:

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, AssessmentAttemptDetailsEntity> assessmentAttemptDetailsEntityConsumerFactory() {
            JsonDeserializer<AssessmentAttemptDetailsEntity> 
            deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
            deserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.lte.assessment.assessments");//your package
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(config,deserializer);
    }
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. Edited the question with code

Comment: It looks like the one that I add is getting overridden somewhere else. What is the best place to put it.

Comment: have you checked your  application.property?

Comment: Run it in a debugger and set a breakpoint in the deserializer.

Comment: I had multiple factories in the config which caused the issue. Fixed it now