# spring Kafka model is not in the trusted packages

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm working on the micro services with `spring-Kafka-2.1.5` and `spring-boot-2.0.5`

First service will produce some messages to kafka and second one will consume them, while consuming I'm having the issue

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.service1.model.TopicMessage' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang, com.service2.model.ConsumeMessage]. 
If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
```

So from the error message this is the `com.service1.model.TopicMessage` serialized model of service1. But I'm trying to Deserialize message into model `com.service2.model.ConsumeMessage` which is in service2 and having this issue

I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964530/spring-kafka-issue-while-deserialising-kafka-message-class-not-in-a-trusted), and tried below format and also from documentation [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#serdes)

Below is my configs

```
  @Bean(name = "kafkaConsumerConfig")
   public Map<String, Object> kafkaConsumerConfig() {

    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();

    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, clientId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, offsetconfig);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, autoCommitInterval);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, sessionTimeout);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, maxPollRecords);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, enableAutoCommit);

     }
```

**kafkaConsumerFactory**

```
@Bean(name = "kafkaConsumerFactory")
public ConsumerFactory<String, ConsumeMessage> kafkaConsumerFactory()        {

    JsonDeserializer<ConsumeMessage> 
    deserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>();
    deserializer.addTrustedPackages("com.service2.model");
return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, ConsumeMessage>(kafkaConsumerConfig(),new StringDeserializer(),deserializer);

}
```

**kafkaListenerContainerFactory**

```
 @Bean(name = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
 public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConsumeMessage > kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {

    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, ConsumeMessage > factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

    factory.setConcurrency(Integer.parseInt(threads));
    factory.setBatchListener(true);
    factory.setConsumerFactory(kafkaConsumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setPollTimeout(Long.parseLong(pollTimeout));
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AckMode.BATCH);

    return factory;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disable `header precedence` in the deserializer:

```
/**
 * Construct an instance with the provided target type, and
 * useHeadersIfPresent with a default {@link ObjectMapper}.
 * @param targetType the target type.
 * @param useHeadersIfPresent true to use headers if present and fall back to target
 * type if not.
 * @since 2.2
 */
public JsonDeserializer(Class<? super T> targetType, boolean useHeadersIfPresent) {
```

The `useHeadersIfPresent` argument must be configured to `false`. That way an `inferred` type is going to be used and the header value is going to be ignored.

If you don't use `spring-kafka-2.2`, you should consider to implement your own `JsonDeserializer` with similar logic: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/support/serializer/JsonDeserializer.java

Comment: That's not related to this question. Although it isn't clear what is your concern on the matter: you just need to migrate your AckMode config to that new style.

Comment: ya that's a dummy question sir, but may I know why this `addTrustedPackages("com.service2.model");` is not working for me

Comment: Because you fail on the `com.service1.model` and that's is fully different package and possible doesn't exist in the service #2.

Comment: `com.service1.model.TopicMessage` is coming from a message header; adding a different package to the trusted packages won't change that. You can also configure a type mapper on the producer to map `com.service1.model.TopicMessage` to a token, say, `TopicMessage` and then similar mapping on the consumer to map `com.service2.model.TopicMessage` from `TopicMessage`. This is also made easier in 2.2 because you can do it using properties. https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/_reference.html#serdes

Comment: You can also use a `StringDeserializer`(or `BytesDeserialier) in conjunction with a `StringJsonMessageConverter` (or `BytesJsonMessageConverter`) and the framework will automatically determine the target type based on the `@KafkaListener` method signature. Just add the converter as a `@Bean` and boot will wire it in.

Comment: is this to support `@KafkaHandler` annotation, which mean topic can have different type payloads and listener thread can map to corresponding method annotated with `@KafkaHandler`

Comment: That's correct. The conversion from JSON string is going to be done by the `MessageConverter` then instead.